# how to determine stock target price

Tags: stocks

I see tipranks provides stock target price. But how do experts determine a stock target price? I assume they use public information, such as financial statement and models. If anyone knows more details, please share.

Comment: OK, I'm no expert but give me any stock symbol that you like and I'll give you a target price.  Ignoring my momentary clairvoyance,  what makes you think that Tipranks is an expert and can accurately predict future price? Or anyone else for that matter?

Comment: I understand your point. But, I am just curious what kind methods they use to calculate the target price. Of course, no model or calculation is perfect. I just want to know the calculation process.

Comment: I think after I know their calculation process, I will understand their pros and cons. This is my point.

Comment: You can answer your own question by reading books about "financial modeling" and "valuation".

Comment: Do you have any particular books in your mind that you think are very useful?

Comment: Please use "@<username>" when replying to comments, otherwise the person whom you are trying to interact with won't be notified of your comment.